# How can I access variable-named cookies from a Codeception acceptance test?

Tags: cookies, selenium, acceptance-testing, codeception

I'm writing some acceptance tests in Codeception, and I want to check if a cookie exists. Normally you can do that with [the seeCookie() method](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser) (e.g., `$I->seeCookie( 'auth_logged_in' )`, but in my case, the name of the cookie includes a user-specific hash (e.g., `auth_logged_in_49d4ab732056d505c2c751e2f7a5d842`).

It looks like the existing methods -- like WebGuy->seeCookie(), WebGuy->grabCookie(), etc -- all expect me to pass the exact name of the cookie, rather than being able to check for a partial name.

I looked at how the `WebDriver->seeCookie()` method works, and it calls `$this->webDriver->manage()->getCookies();`, so I tried [adding a WebHelper method](http://codeception.com/docs/03-ModulesAndHelpers) to create a `WebGuy->seeCookieMatches()` method that uses a regex to check the cookie name, but it doesn't have a `$this->webDriver` member like `WebDriver` does.

> ErrorException: Undefined property: Codeception\Module\WebHelper::$webDriver

Is there a way for the `WebHelper` class to access the members of the `WebDriver` class?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do this by using [the getModule() method](http://codeception.com/docs/03-ModulesAndHelpers#Connecting-Modules).

So now my WebHelper method looks like this:

```php
public function seeCookieMatches( $pattern ) {
    // Codeception 2.x      
    $cookies = $this->getModule( 'PhpBrowser' )->client->getCookieJar()->all();

    // Codeception 1.x
    $cookies = $this->getModule( 'PhpBrowser' )->session->getDriver()->getClient()->getCookieJar()->all();

    // [...]
}
```